# Nested or multiple case functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a nested case when query. My table has ID, code1 and code2 columns.
`create table as select ID, code1 case when code1 is not null then 'yes' else (select code2, case when code 2 is not null then 'no' else 'NA' from table) from table`

What I want to achieve is that if code1 is null, I want to go ahead and check for code2 being null or not null. If code1 is not null then it gets a tag 'yes' right away without any checks on code2.
What would be the right way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with creating a table, you get the id and a tag with your specification

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable SELECT ID,
    CASE
        WHEN code1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes'
        WHEN code2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END tag FROM
    table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ID, code1,
       CASE 
         WHEN code1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' 
         WHEN code2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no'
         ELSE 'NA'
       END AS tag
FROM tablename
```

Each `WHEN` branch is processed only if the previous ones failed.